# Ansible to connect to RDS from an EC2 and delete schema

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

Is it possible to use 'mysql_db' module in Ansible to login to RDS in AWS from an EC2?
We are able to login/connect with RDS from EC2 server, but when we try to do that using ansible, it gives error.
We don't want to use Ansible 'rds' module to directly connect with RDS but trying to accomplish the same using mysql_db module.

Here is my Ansible task:

```
- name: Delete database with name 'testdb' in RDS
  mysql_db:
    login_host: "xxxxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com"
    login_password: "{{ mysql_user_password }}"
    login_user: "{{ mysql_user }}"
    login_port: 3306
    name: "{{ db_name }}"
    state: absent
```

Even we are providing the hostname to connect with but in the error it's still trying to login to localhost instead of RDS.

Error:

```
TASK [mysql57rds : Delete database with name 'testdb' in RDS] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /mnt/c/ansible/testdb-ansible/roles/mysql57rds/tasks/main.yml:35

fatal: [10.0.x.x]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "ca_cert": null,
            "check_hostname": null,
            "check_implicit_admin": false,
            "client_cert": null,
            "client_key": null,
            "collation": "",
            "config_file": "/root/.my.cnf",
            "config_overrides_defaults": false,
            "connect_timeout": 30,
            "dump_extra_args": null,
            "encoding": "",
            "force": false,
            "hex_blob": false,
            "ignore_tables": [],
            "login_host": "xxxxxxxx.rds.amazonaws.com",
            "login_password": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER",
            "login_port": 3306,
            "login_unix_socket": null,
            "login_user": "admin",
            "master_data": 0,
            "name": [
                "testdb"
            ],
            "quick": true,
            "restrict_config_file": false,
            "single_transaction": false,
            "skip_lock_tables": false,
            "state": "absent",
            "target": null,
            "unsafe_login_password": false,
            "use_shell": false
        }
    },
    "msg": "unable to connect to database, check login_user and login_password are correct or /root/.my.cnf has the credentials. Exception message: (1045, \"Access denied for user 'admin'@'localhost' (using password: YES)\")"
}
```

Can someone please suggest on it?

Comment: I'd guess you are not being careful about the encoding of `mysql_user_password` and it is not ending up being what you think it is. A common bug would be `-e mysql_user_password="pa$word"` ends up with `mysql_user_password=pa` or any number of jinja2 misunderstandings. I'd start by checking it with `- debug: var=mysql_user_password` or similar

Comment: Hi @mdaniel I have printed the password, and it's reading it correctly.



`TASK [mysql57rdsseed : debug] *********************************
task path: xxxxx/main.yml
ok: [10.0.x.x] => {
    "mysql_user_password": "test@123$"
}`

Though, my question is; is it possible to connect with RDS (mysql) in AWS and do delete/create DB operations ? The playbook is supposed to connect from an EC2 machine to RDS.

Comment: Yes, that's the whole point of a database to allow connections to it. I just replied based on the error message given, and my experience with text containing special characters in jinja2. If you truly can just use `mysql -p` to successfully connect to the server, then I guess use `command:` and chalk this up to the mysteries of life

Comment: yeah, I am doing it using `script:` module and it's running fine. Thank you for your responses.